# Passing Generic List into SelectLista

Tags: c#

I know you can't pass in a non IEnumerable based object into an ASP.NET MVC SelectList helper method (as it expects an `IEnumerable` for the first param).  I have a generic list `List<OurCustomType>` and OurCustomType has properties for things such as value, etc. for the dropdown.

So if I can't pass in a generic object to an IEnumerable, what other options do I have here if I still want to use the SelectList helper?

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`, so `List<T>` already implements `IEnumerable`. It should be fine. For example:

```
List<int> genericList = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<int> genericSequence = genericList;
IEnumerable weakSequence = genericSequence;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the definition of [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) in the framework docs you will see that it inherits off the non-generic IEnumerable. As List<T> inherits IEnumerable<T>, and hence IEnumerable, you'll be able to pass it into your SelectList without problems.

This was done precisely for this issue - backwards compatability with existing non-generic code, although it does make it a tad annoying when implementing your own IEnumerable, as you have to provide the non-generic version as well. Thank the lovely people on the BCL team for that :D